# swagger-ui does not get api information for Spring MVC API

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, swagger-ui

I'using Spring MVC and Spring Security and I wanted to bring Swagger documentation. I followed the tutorial [hier](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) and got a full json document under the url .../v2/api-docs.

But when I turned also the swagger-ui on I got an error page under the url .../swagger-ui.html like on the screenshot: everything is undefined, he does not see my api.
[image]

I know that sometimes Swagger-Ui can confront with Spring settings and the requests are not filtered out with security. Can it be the problem in this case? What could I switch off to make it work?

Or it can be a problem of classes marked with `@ControllerAdvice`. I use it for ExceptionResolver:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{...}
```

Here is my Maven snippet:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

UPDATE My SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;  
private PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedProvider;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    Map<String, List<GrantedAuthority>> rolesAuthorities = userDao.getRolesWithAutorities();

    userDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
    UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = 
            new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(userDetailsService);
    preAuthenticatedProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedProvider);
    preAuthenticatedProvider.setThrowExceptionWhenTokenRejected(true);
}

@Override //(does not help)
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {     
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**/v2/api-docs/**", 
            "/**/configuration/ui/**", "/**/swagger-resources/**", "/**/configuration/security/**", "/**/swagger-ui.html");

 }

@Bean
public SmUserFailureHandler smUserFailureHandler(){
    return new SmUserFailureHandler();
}   

@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    AccessDeniedHandlerImpl handler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
    handler.setErrorPage("/errorpage/");        
    return handler;     
}

public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter() throws Exception
{

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new DelegateRequestMatchingFilter(
            new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("...**"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("..."),
            smUserFailureHandler());

    siteMinderFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());   
    siteMinderFilter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
    siteMinderFilter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
    return siteMinderFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  

  ...

http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

 RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter smFilter = siteMinderFilter();
 http.addFilter(smFilter);
 ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http.authorizeRequests();     
  http = registry.and();
http.formLogin().loginPage("/resource/User/Login/").failureHandler(smUserFailureHandler());
  http.formLogin().failureUrl("/resource/User/Login/").failureHandler(smUserFailureHandler());

  http.csrf().disable();
  http.headers().cacheControl().disable();

}
}
```

Comment: it might help - https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/swagger-example

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061496/swagger-maven-plugin-documentation-is-not-generated/43065956#43065956

Comment: Why you have the antMatchers like this /**/v2/api-docs/** ? SpringFox doesn't add any prefix to the swagger endpoints. Try to see the spring logs for all endpoints and check the swagger endpoints names and match it against that.

Comment: @HenriqueMartins, what do you mean "against that"? I tried to match them differetnly, it does not work at all. My other swagger endpoint funktion well: I receive normal jsons

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable access to the swagger endpoints in your spring security configuration.

These are the endpoints created by springfox:

```
2017-05-10 15:07:15.141  INFO 22472 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-10 15:07:15.146  INFO 22472 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
2017-05-10 15:07:15.147  INFO 22472 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
2017-05-10 15:07:15.148  INFO 22472 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
```

Add this method to your spring security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: it does not work. It even does not filter out this URIs

Comment: Can you put your spring security config class here? It might be something in there.  Also, can you try to curl the swagger endpoints? If it gives 403 its security.

Comment: I added the security configuration